# Error while running rbenv install on OS X 10.11.2: config.status: error: could not create GNUmakefile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zsh, rbenv, osx-elcapitan

Trying to follow the instructions from here -- https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan -- to install Ruby on Rails, but I'm getting the following error:

```
➜  ~  rbenv install 2.2.3
Downloading ruby-2.2.3.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/df795f2f99860745a416092a4004b016ccf77e8b82dec956b120f18bdc71edce
Installing ruby-2.2.3...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.2 using ruby-build 20150928)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/l3/skxhsvw51wz7fnn2v1v4d3sh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20151222232425.95349
Results logged to /var/folders/l3/skxhsvw51wz7fnn2v1v4d3sh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20151222232425.95349.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for nroff... /usr/bin/nroff
.ext/include/x86_64-darwin15/ruby/config.h updated
ruby library version = 2.2.0
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating GNUmakefile
awk: syntax error at source line 1 source file ./confyJCFwP/subs.awk
 context is
     >>> BEGIN <<<  {
awk: bailing out at source line 275
config.status: error: could not create GNUmakefile
```

And then checking the log file, it says the same thing at the end:

```
...
.ext/include/x86_64-darwin15/ruby/config.h updated
 ruby library version = 2.2.0
 configure: creating ./config.status
 config.status: creating GNUmakefile
 awk: syntax error at source line 1 source file ./confyJCFwP/subs.awk
  context is
      >>> BEGIN <<<  {
 awk: bailing out at source line 275
 config.status: error: could not create GNUmakefile
```

How can I fix this? I recently ran `brew upgrade` on everything and it seemed to complete successfully.

Note: I don't know if it's relevant but my shell is ZSH (via oh-my-zsh).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going through my PATH settings in ~/.zshrc and broke the entire path out into individual lines (there were a lot). I figured that way I could comment each PATH setting out individually if I thought it might matter. As it turns out, I was right. I commented out the following:

```
# export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:$PATH"
# export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:$PATH"
# export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:$PATH"
# export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:$PATH"
# export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:$PATH"
# export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:$PATH"
```

I then re-ran the command and it completed successfully.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: The lesson here is not to mix RVM and rbenv.

Comment: You shouldn't set your RVM paths like that to begin with.

Comment: Good to know. Hope it helps someone else.